# Wordpress Making ONLY most recent post display on front-page.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble figuring out how to make sure that only my most recent post is displayed on the front page of my front-page.php file, since I have some custom post types and would like for my most recent post to just display below my most recent of the custom post type.

Sorry if this makes no sense, basically I just want to know what to add to the wordpress loop to make sure that it only gives me the most recent post, and no others.

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="section_title">
            <h2>Recent Update:</h2>
        </div>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn right">Read More</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="front_page_image">
        <img src="images/annoyed_victoria.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook to limit posts_per_page to 1.

Add the following to your functions.php.

```
function my_main_query($query){
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_main_query');
```

Thank to Nathan Dawson for pointing out the flaws of query_posts().

See the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) for more information on the loop and how to alter it.

Comment: Genius! It works! Thanks, can't believe I haven't picked up on this trick yet considering how much I have learned!

Comment: I would advise using pre_get_posts instead of query_posts. It's much more efficient. Take a look at the opening paragraph of the codex for query_posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Nathan! I have updated my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should fetch the most recent 5 posts.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><span class="visit">See post</span></a>
<?php endwhile;?>
```